# Need help getting sum of fields on Commerce Line Items

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a field called line item weight on every line item.
i want to sum up the line item weight fields to get a result we are calling total order weight

I'm thinking I should use rules to do this, but I am not sure how to go about looping through the line items to get the sum of the order.

If it helps, I already have one rule in place that upon adding a product to the cart, 
takes the product weight, multiplies by the quantity and fills the value into the line item weight field.

Comment: Randy Fay has suggested following along with his tutorial here - http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1721

Comment: Additionally, if you use an actual weight field from the Physical Fields project, there's an API in the Commerce Physical Products module for determining the total weight of an order using the weight fields on your product line items. I'd put this as an answer to your question, but it sounds like you're using custom fields making this a non-answer. : P

Comment: Thanks Ryan I am working through Randy's tutorials now and I will try doing as you suggest.  I think I may have been trying to reinvent the wheel.  BTW Hope to see you at DrupalCon and I'll remember to brush my teeth :)

Comment: There is also further discussion of this topic here - http://drupal.org/node/1312414

Comment: Since I am not a coder, I will try to expose the Order Total weight functionality to Rules that is in the Physical API by applying a patch I found here - http://drupal.org/node/1344962

Comment: I have no luck with this so far